# Getting a section header to stick to the top of a wrapper div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a section header to stick to the top of a wrapper div, but the wrapper div needs to have a set height and the overflow set to scroll.

I've seen [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bluebomber/tqusn2et/) (jsfiddle) that achieves exactly what I'm looking for minus the fact that it doesn't have a wrapper div with a set height or overflow.

[Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/bluebomber/nwt58L8j/) (jsfiddle) the same example with the wrapper div added with set height and overflow. You can see that it is not working.

Does anyone have a solution for this, or a work around?

This is the wrapper css that is being used:

```
.wrapper {
   height: 500px;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Change the parrent from window to wrapper http://jsfiddle.net/uz27jjpn/

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos Why not stick that in the answer section? :)

Comment: Because it's not complete (it has some problems with divs overlapping on the scrollbar) so i just wanted to help a little not to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Thanasis already stated in the comments you have to change the scrolling context from `window` to `.wrapper`.

To avoid the 100%-width fixed div to overlap the scrollbars I know no different way than setting the width to `calc(100% - 17px)` where 17px is the hard-coded width of the scrollbar.

Find the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nwt58L8j/6/